# ansible-inventory --list command failing with gce plugin error: gce inventory plugin cannot start

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, ansible

I have verified my Python3 , module path and collections path on a new Ansible control server (Debian 11). However, when pointing the `ansible-inventory --list` command at a Google cloud gcp.yml inventory file, I am getting this error:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/user/CODE/ops/ansible/inventory/gcp-dynamic/demo3/gcp.yml with
ansible_collections.google.cloud.plugins.inventory.gcp_compute plugin: gce inventory plugin cannot start: Failed to import the required Python library
(google-auth) on server's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location
```

This is the full inventory command:
`ansible-inventory --list -i /path/to/gcp.yml`

This is the gcp.yml file:

```
---
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - project9
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: /home/user/.config/credentials.json

# setup group parasing prefix=inventory label
keyed_groups:
  - key: labels
    prefix: demo3
```

This is my `ansible --version` output:

```
ansible [core 2.13.2]
  config file = /home/user/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections
  executable location = /home/user/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

this is the output from `pip3 show google-auth`:

```
Name: google-auth
Version: 2.10.0
Summary: Google Authentication Library
Home-page: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-packages@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: cachetools, pyasn1-modules, rsa, six
Required-by:
```

In my ~/.ansible.cfg I have this:

```
# (pathspec) Colon separated paths in which Ansible will search for Modules.
library=/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/modules:/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Ansible but familiar with Google Cloud. The Python libraries use [`google-auth`](https://pypi.org/project/google-auth/) to authenticate using Application Default Credentials (for Service Accounts). This Python module appears missing from your Ansible config. Do you have a way to add specific modules? If Ansible is leveraging your default Python environment, then if you `pip install google-auth` and try again, it may work.

Comment: `pip3 install google-auth`, most probably, `pip install google-auth` will install it on the OP's Python 2.x version.

Comment: I definitely have the google-auth module installed. I can run python3 at the CLI and do `import google.auth`, this works just fine.

Comment: What does `pip3 show google-auth` gives you? (Add that in an [edit] of your question, preferably, not in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

me also struggling with this kind of errors, seems like I've install all the plugins and my python3 seems to be in the correct path and used properly by ansible.

after some debugging that takes half a day, I am trying this solution instead:

1. check the plugin that you use, for example requests and google-auth by running this command `python3 -m pip show google-auth` this will show you the version and path of the plugin installed.
2. after i found out that maybe the plugin is just having an issue with the version, I tried to revert back the old version of google-auth and request. and finally it worked.

if you figuring how to install specific pip package version, run this command `python3 -m pip install google-auth==<version>`

in my case, i am using **google-auth** version 2.3.3 and **requests** version 2.25.0

Answer (score 0):

I went back and forth between installing Ansible via pip as the [ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html) prescribe, and 'apt'.

I finally got this dynamic inventory working with this setup:

Debian11 base VM from GCP , then do everything as root:
python --comes installed (/usr/bin/python3)
pip
ansible
google-auth

I made sure to do all the additional package adds as root and not have my installation geared toward a single user:

pip --installed pip with apt: `sudo apt install python3-pip`

ansible --installed with apt: `sudo apt install ansible`

google-auth --also installed as root: `sudo pip3 install google-auth`

It seems the major issue was mis-matching installation methods between `pip` and `apt`.  In this case everything sorted itself out when I did everything via apt and did not install Ansible via pip.